# Merge employee and dependent info

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I have two sheets, one with employee information (including SSN for unique ID) and the other with dependent information (each dependent has the SSN of the employee they belong to.)

The "Employee" sheet does not include all employees in the company, but the "Dependent" sheet does.

Is there a way to have excel check the "Dependent" sheet (looking for a matching SSN) and if found, copy that row and insert under corresponding employees?

*IMPORTANT - Dependents need to show under parent employee

I have 2,500 employees that I need to match up dependents with, so any help is very appreciated.

Let me know if more info would be useful.

Comment: This would be far easier if you flipped what you were trying to do. I.E. Pull the Employee into the dependant sheet. You could do it with an Excel formula and just add the necessary # of columns. Once done, you can just filter out the rows that didn't find an employee... much simpler than inserting rows that don't match the headings for your first sheet.

Comment: That's good thinking - I am going to see if I can make that work.  (I have had my brain buried in this for too long)

Comment: @DanielCook  I've been working with this new idea and I can't figure out which excel formula should I use.  Any tips?

Comment: @danielCook I don't understand how a vlookup will accomplish this. I need the dependent info to show in the row(s) under the employee they belong to. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want someone to be able to make the formula for you, you'd have to show us sample data. Basically you want to Vlookup using the employee # from the dependant sheet, searching in the Employee sheet. Use however many you need 1 for each column.

Comment: @DanielCook - here is a link to a Google spreadsheet (I'm new to stackoverflow and don't know how to share flies) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlRB7kLDi__TdFB3cmRWdjcxMHVlUTc2b21jY2V5SWc#gid=1

Answer (score 0):

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)
```

nice little tutorial here:

http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm

Comment: @danielCook  I don't understand how a vlookup will accomplish this.  I need the dependent info to show in the row(s) under the employee they belong to.  Am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean by under the row? you actually mean if the row is 1, you wantt he employee to belong to row 2?

Comment: If employee is in row 1 their dependents would be in row 2, 3, 4 (depending on how many dependents they have)